# filtering field's value depends on another field's in OpenErp 7.0

Tags: field, filtering, openerp-7

I'm learning OpenErp 7.0, but I'm greenhorn yet.

I've two fields in my class:

```
 _columns = {
    'used_partner':fields.many2one('res.partner', domain="[('is_company','=',True)]"),
    'worker':fields.many2one('res.partner', domain="[('parent_id','=',.?.?.?.?.?.)]"),
```

1./ In my form view I could choose used_partner from res.partner table, where is_company are True.

2./ I'd like to see in my form view only workers from res.partner table, where parent_id = used_partner id.

What is the best way to resolve this problem?
Any help would be appreciated!
(Sorry my poor english!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (IMHO) solution is:

```
_columns = {
    'used_partner':fields.many2one('res.partner', domain="[('is_company','=',True)]"),
    'worker':fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Worker'),
```

In the form of my view:

```
<field name="used_partner" />
<field name="worker" domain="[('parent_id','=',used_partner)]" />
```

This works fine for me!

Comment: Thank you for posting a working solution!  Don't forget to accept it when you can.